The rotation animation runs in several cells. How to fix it?
Good afternoon everyone. I can’t understand why, when you click a button, the animation runs in another cell?
For example, I click on cell 1, the animation starts on cell 4.
Cells are redrawn after the animation runs. I made an closure for this.
This is link video [https://www.youtube.com/shorts/8qvAIxn61zU][1]
This method for animation icon.
// MARK: - Animation.
private extension CellSeries {
    /// This is method, for work the animation.
    func startAnimation(_ angle: CGFloat, completionAnimation: @escaping () -> Void) {
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: self.style.Time.animationAngle,
            delay: .zero,
            options: [.curveLinear],
            animations: {
                self.buttonTitle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
            }, completion: { _ in
                /// The animation stops.
                completionAnimation()
            })
    }
}


This is CollectionView.
// MARK: - Protocol.
protocol IMainRepairViewLogic: AnyObject {
    /// Отображение устройств MainRepairDevicesModel.ViewModel.Device
    func renderDevices(viewModel: [MainRepairDevicesModel.ViewModel.FilterItem])

    /// Отображение данный модельного ряда, для устройства MainRepairDevicesModel.ViewModel.Device
    func renderSeries(viewModel: [MainRepairSeriesModel.ViewModel.Series])
}

// MARK: - MainRepairViewController
final class MainRepairViewController: FilterCollectionViewController {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var iterator: IMainRepairIterator?

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private let style = GlobalStyleSettings.self
    /// Модель для отображение списка устройств.
    private var modelDeviceDisplay: [MainRepairDevicesModel.ViewModel.FilterItem] = []
    /// Модель для отображение списка серии для определенного устройства.
    private var modelSeriesDisplay: [MainRepairSeriesModel.ViewModel.Series] = []
    /// Текущий индекс устройства, например iPad, iPhone, и. т. п.
    private var currentIndexDevice: Int = 0
    /// Текущий индекс серии например iPhone 5, и. т. п.
    private var currentIndexSeries: Int = 0
    /// Текущее устройство.
    private var currentDevice = MainRepairSeriesModel.RequestSeries.Devices(
        deviceID: 0,
        parentID: 0,
        title: ""
    )

    // MARK: - Initializator
    init(title: String) {
        super.init()
        headerMenu = HeaderMenuView(
            title: "iPhone",
            step: GlobalTitles.TitleForHeaderStep.first,
            isBack: true,
            delegate: self
        )
        // делегаты FilterCollectionView.
        handlerFilterCellDelegate = self
        delegateSettingFilterCell = self
        // делегаты VerticalCollectionView.
        handlerCellDelegate = self
        delegateSettingCell = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: - Настройки Filter Cell CollectionView.
extension MainRepairViewController: IHandlerFilterCollectionDelegate {
    func getFiltersCount() -> Int {
        modelDeviceDisplay.count
    }

    func itemFilterSelect(index: Int) {
        self.currentIndexDevice = index
        modelDeviceDisplay.enumerated().forEach {
            let curentStatus: Status = currentIndexDevice == $0.element.index ? .activity : .notActive
            modelDeviceDisplay[$0.element.index].status = curentStatus
        }
        reloadCollectionFilterView()
        fitchDevice()
    }
}

extension MainRepairViewController: ISettingFilterCollectionDelegate {
    func registerFilterCell(collectionFilterView collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        collectionView.register(CellDevices.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellDevices.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func createFilterCell(
        collectionFilterView collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: CellDevices.reuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath
        ) as? CellDevices {
            let currentDevice = modelDeviceDisplay[indexPath.item]
            if let image = UIImage(named: currentDevice.imageName) {
                cell.reloadData(image: image)
            }
            cell.changeAction(status: currentDevice.status)
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func calculateFilterCellSize() -> CGSize {
        let size = style.Size.cellDevice
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}

// MARK: - Настройки Vertical Cell CollectionView.
extension MainRepairViewController: IHandlerCollectionCell {
    func itemSelect(index: Int) { }

    func getCellCount(section: Int) -> Int {
        modelSeriesDisplay.count
    }
}

extension MainRepairViewController: ISettingCollectionCell {
    func createCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: CellSeries.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath
        ) as? CellSeries {
            let series = modelSeriesDisplay[indexPath.item]
            cell.reloadData(index: indexPath.item, series: series)
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.changeVisibility(isHidden: series.isHide)
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func registerCell(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        collectionView.register(CellSeries.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellSeries.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func calculateCellSize(indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // Количество моделей в текущем модельном ряде.
        let currentGadget = modelSeriesDisplay[indexPath.item]
        let countModel = CGFloat(currentGadget.models.count)
        // Отступы ячейки.
        let padding = style.Padding.allHorizontal * 2
        // Высота ячейки.
        let heightCell = style.Size.cellSeries.height
        var totalHeight: CGFloat = heightCell
        /*
        switch currentGadget.isHide {
        case .hide:
            break
        case .notHide, .unknown:
            // К высоте ячейки += высота ячейки * на количество моделей.
            totalHeight += (totalHeight * countModel)
        }
         */
        totalHeight += (totalHeight * countModel)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width - padding, height: totalHeight)
    }
}

// MARK: - Render
extension MainRepairViewController: IMainRepairViewLogic {
    func renderDevices(viewModel: [MainRepairDevicesModel.ViewModel.FilterItem]) {
        for (index, element) in viewModel.enumerated() {
            let item = MainRepairDevicesModel.ViewModel.FilterItem(
                id: element.id,
                index: index,
                title: element.title,
                imageName: element.imageName,
                status: index == currentIndexDevice ? .activity : .notActive
            )
            self.modelDeviceDisplay.append(item)
        }
        reloadCollectionFilterView()
        fitchDevice()
    }

    func renderSeries(viewModel: [MainRepairSeriesModel.ViewModel.Series]) {
        self.modelSeriesDisplay = viewModel
        self.currentIndexSeries = 0
        reloadCollectionView()
    }
}

// MARK: - Logic.
private extension MainRepairViewController {
    func fitchDevice() {
        currentDevice = MainRepairSeriesModel.RequestSeries.Devices(from: modelDeviceDisplay[currentIndexDevice])
        iterator?.fetchSeriesAndModel(device: currentDevice)
    }
}

// MARK: - Navigation.
extension MainRepairViewController: IHeaderMenuDelegate {
    func backToView() { }
}

// MARK: - Delegate.
extension MainRepairViewController: ICellSeriesDelegate {
    func handlerCell(index: Int) {
        self.currentIndexSeries = index
        self.modelSeriesDisplay.enumerated().forEach {
            if $0.offset != self.currentIndexSeries {
                self.modelSeriesDisplay[$0.offset].isHide = true
            }
        }
        self.modelSeriesDisplay[self.currentIndexSeries].isHide.toggle()
        reloadCollectionView()
    }

    func checkItem(index: Int, tag: Int) {
        let currentGadget = modelSeriesDisplay[index].models[tag]
        let convertModel = MainRepairSeriesModel.RequestSeries.Devices(from: currentGadget)
        iterator?.nextScene(device: convertModel)
    }
}


This is cell.
import UIKit

protocol ICellSeriesDelegate: AnyObject {
    func handlerCell(index: Int)
    func checkItem(index: Int, tag: Int)
}

final class ButtonForCellSeries: UIButton {
    var isShow: Bool

    internal init(isShow: Bool) {
        self.isShow = isShow
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

final class CellSeries: UICollectionViewCell {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var delegate: ICellSeriesDelegate!

    // MARK: - Public properties
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CellSeries.cell"

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private lazy var labelTitle = createLabel()
    private lazy var stackVertical = createStack()
    private lazy var buttonTitle = createButton()

    private let style = GlobalStyleSettings.self
    private var index: Int = 0
    private var isShow: Bool = true

    // MARK: - Initializator
    convenience init(delegate: ICellSeriesDelegate?) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addUIView()
        setupConfiguration()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
    func reloadData(index: Int, series: MainRepairSeriesModel.ViewModel.Series) {
        self.index = index
        self.isShow = series.isHide
        labelTitle.text = series.title
        buttonTitle.tag = index
        generateContent(models: series.models)
    }

    func changeVisibility(isHidden: Bool) {
        labelTitle.text = "\(isHidden)"
        if isHidden {
            labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.green
            self.buttonTitle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .zero)

            #warning("TODO: This is method, don`t work correctly")
            //  startAnimation(.zero, completionAnimation: {})
        } else {
            labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.red
            self.buttonTitle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: style.Angle.turnIconButton)
        }
    }

    private func generateContent(models: [MainRepairSeriesModel.ViewModel.Model]) {
        while stackVertical.arrangedSubviews.count < models.count {
            stackVertical.addArrangedSubview(ButtonViewCell(delegate: self))
        }

        let zipArray = zip(stackVertical.arrangedSubviews, models)
        for (index, model) in zipArray.enumerated() {
            if let currentButton = model.0 as? ButtonViewCell {
                currentButton.reloadData(title: model.1.title, tag: index)
                setupButton(currentButton)
            }
        }
        // Прячем лишние кнопки
        for (index, currentButton) in stackVertical.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
            currentButton.isHidden = !(index < models.count)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Add UIView.
private extension CellSeries {
    func addUIView() {
        let views: [UIView] = [
            labelTitle,
            buttonTitle,
            stackVertical
        ]
        views.forEach(addSubview)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI configuration.
private extension CellSeries {
    func setupConfiguration() {
        buttonTitle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showList), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

// MARK: - Add constraint.
private extension CellSeries {
    func setupLayout() {
        let sizeButton = style.Size.sizeButton
        let padding = style.Padding.allHorizontal
        let heightCell = style.Size.cellSeries.height
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            labelTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            labelTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            labelTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightCell),

            buttonTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sizeButton.width),
            buttonTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: sizeButton.height),
            buttonTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelTitle.centerYAnchor),
            buttonTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelTitle.rightAnchor, constant: -padding),

            stackVertical.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackVertical.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            stackVertical.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            stackVertical.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupButton(_ button: ButtonViewCell) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeparator(_ separator: SeparatorViewCell) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            separator.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            separator.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            separator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2)
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Fabric.
private extension CellSeries {
    func createLabel() -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = Theme.mainColor
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: Styles.Fonts.average, weight: .semibold)
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1
        label.layer.cornerRadius = Styles.Radius.radiusTextField
        label.layer.borderColor = Theme.mainColor.cgColor
        label.backgroundColor = Colors.grey
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }

    func createStack() -> UIStackView {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.layer.borderColor = Theme.mainColor.cgColor
        stack.layer.cornerRadius = style.Radius.radiusCell
        stack.layer.borderWidth = style.Border.little
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stack
    }

    func createButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "Images/Buttons/leftArrowFill")?.withTintColor(Theme.mainColor)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Action.
private extension CellSeries {
    @objc func showList() {
        startAnimation(style.Angle.turnIconButton, completionAnimation: {
            // After the animation is completed, we transfer the data.
            self.delegate.handlerCell(index: self.index)
        })
    }
}

// MARK: - Animation.
private extension CellSeries {
    /// This is method, for work the animation.
    func startAnimation(_ angle: CGFloat, completionAnimation: @escaping () -> Void) {
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: self.style.Time.animationAngle,
            delay: .zero,
            options: [.curveLinear],
            animations: {
                self.buttonTitle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
            }, completion: { _ in
                /// The animation stops.
                completionAnimation()
            })
    }
}

// MARK: - Delegate.
extension CellSeries: IButtonViewCellDelegate {
    func checkButton(tag: Int) {
        delegate.checkItem(index: index, tag: tag)
    }
}


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/8qvAIxn61zU


You posted several hundred lines of code. It's nearly impossible to follow in the tiny text window in an SO post, and would require far more time than most of us can dedicate to your question. You need to provide a detailed roadmap of how the code is structured, what it is supposed to do, and where it is failing to do that. You should create and upload a minimal reproducible example to Github and post a link to the project here.
